# Convert table to binary matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a table with two column that contains memberid (id of member that reviews product) and productid (id of product that reviewer write review for it).

For example:

```
    memberid  productid
     A             x
     A             y
     A             z
     B             x
     B             z
     B             w
```

I want convert this table to binary matrix:

```
   x y z w . . .
a  1 1 1 0
b  1 0 1 1
.
.
.
```

Please help me.

Comment: I think your `b` row in your example is incorrect. Shouldn't the `w` column be a 1 as well?

Comment: I correct thip fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `splitapply` to first group everything by the first column and then for each group check membership with the second column.

```
% Create the data
t = table({'A';'A';'A';'B';'B';'B'}, {'x'; 'y';'z';'x';'z';'w'}, ...
          'VariableNames', {'memberid', 'productid'});

% Group by the first column values
groups = findgroups(t.memberid);

% Get the unique product ids (and maintain their order of appearance)
productids = unique(t.productid, 'stable').';

% Determine which values of the second column exist for each group
membership = splitapply(@(x)ismember(productids, x), t.productid, groups);

%   1     1     1     0
%   1     0     1     1
```

And if you want to, you can wrap that into one line.

```
membership = splitapply(@(x)ismember(unique(t.productid, 'stable').', x), t.productid, findgroups(t.memberid));
```

This result uses the order of the rows and columns in the order that they appear in the table. If you instead want to have the rows and columns be in ascending alphabetical order, then you'll want to define `productids` like this:

```
productids = unique(t.productid).';
```

Or again, as one line

```
membership = splitapply(@(x)ismember(unique(t.productid).', x), t.productid, findgroups(t.memberid));
```

**Update**

Since you're on R2014b, that was before they introduced `splitapply` or `findgroups`. You can instead use this approach:

```
[uids, ~, memberids] = unique(t.memberid, 'stable');
[upids, ~, productids] = unique(t.productid, 'stable');

membership = false(numel(uids), numel(upids));
membership(sub2ind(size(membership), memberids, productids)) = true;
```

Comment: thank you. but this error is show: Undefined function 'findgroups' for input arguments of type 'cell'.  why????

Comment: @Eli What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: R 2014 b. excuse me , i am begineer

Comment: @Eli See my update for an example that doesn't use functions that you don't have.

Comment: thank you. I use this Code: % Create the data
t = table({'A';'A';'A';'B';'B';'B'}, {'x'; 'y';'z';'x';'z';'w'}, ...
          'VariableNames', {'memberid', 'productid'});

[uids, ~, memberids] = unique(t.memberid, 'stable');
[upids, ~, productids] = unique(t.productid, 'stable');

membership = false(numel(uids), numel(upids));
membership(sub2ind(size(membership), memberids, productids)) = true;

Comment: Did you actually display `membership`? It won't just show a binary matrix unless you call `disp(membership)` or type `membership`

Comment: hi again. i have a file with 5.8 milions row . with readtable instruction this file is read. Suppose that is stored in the  t table. uids and upids are initialize correctly. but for line 3 this error be seen. I do not know why :    Error using false
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Comment: @Eli I think it's pretty clear. You ran out of memory because that's a huge dataset. Maybe try breaking up into smaller sections if possible or increase the memory of your machine

Comment: I need all of data.

Comment: @Eli If you re-read my comment, I wasn't suggesting you throw data out, I was suggesting that you process it in batches. So break it into sets of 1 million and then combine at the end.

Comment: How can I do this? Maybe I'm not understand your suggestion,

Comment: So wait. Let's do a little math. How many columns and rows do you expect in the result?

Comment: number of row: 2146277 and number of columns:1231043  (uids and upids)

Comment: hello my friend. I have a question. can you help me?